# How to call Delete method of Database Helper class?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

I want to use below given delete method from my Database Helper class. I asked this 2 times but not such responses i am getting. This is the handler class which i had taken from [androidhive.info](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/)

**Delete Method ( In DatabaseHandler File ):**

```
// Deleting single contact
public void deleteContact(Contact contact) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(TABLE_CONTACTS, KEY_ID + " = ?",new String[] { String.valueOf(contact.getID()) });
    db.close();
}
```

When I am implementing it in **another activity. like this**:

```
String a = Integer.toString(_contactlist.get(position).getID());
            viewHolder.txtid.setText(a.trim());
            viewHolder.txt_name.setText(_contactlist.get(position).getName().trim());
            viewHolder.txt_phone.setText(_contactlist.get(position).getPhoneNumber().trim());

final int temp = position;

Contact pm = db.getContact(temp); //temp is the position of the contact
    db.deleteContact(pm);
```

but when I am using this i am getting an unexpected error i.e. it is deleting only 1 data in row not the selected data.

My **getContact method :**

```
// Getting single contact

Contact getContact(int id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_CONTACTS, new String[] { KEY_ID,
            KEY_NAME, KEY_PH_NO }, KEY_ID + "=?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor != null)
        cursor.moveToFirst();

    Contact contact = new Contact(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
            cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2));
    // return contact
    return contact;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try giving complete query with where clause. Instead of

`db.delete(TABLE_CONTACTS, KEY_ID + " = ?",new String[] { String.valueOf(contact.getID()) });`

use

`db.execSQL("delete * from TABLE_CONTACTS where KEY_ID = "+contact+";");`

Provided, contact should be an integer variable.

Answer (score 0):

> but when I am using this i am getting an unexpected error i.e. it is deleting only 1 data in row not the selected data

deleteContact() method will delete only one record from the database as the KEY_ID seems to be unique. Are you expecting more record(s) to be deleted? Or is it deleting wrong record? You may want to put some debug statements in getContact() to check if it retrieving the wrong contact.

I would like to point out a coding problem in getContact() that may not be related to your issue, but still needs to be corrected.

```
    if (cursor != null)
    cursor.moveToFirst();
```

You are checking the null cursor, but there is no guard if it is null and you are still moving ahead to access the cursor. Also you must check null for moveToFirst(), what if the cursor is non-null, but there are no records to read. The app will crash in both cases.

Comment: I had done this sorry for not mentioning..
My problem is to how to call this delete method in to another Listview activity..

Comment: Make a Database handler class with all its related functions. Then you can use them anywhere in the app without any issue. Another solution can be using ContentResolver object. ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver(); cr.delete( ....);

Comment: This method of mine is in Database handler class but when i am using it and deleting data its only deleting '1st' data of my whole data.!!

Answer (score 0):

the method `deleteContact` closes the database handle.